# How to split strings containing dots based on first and last dot position

Tags: python, string

I have the below file names in a given directory with a standard naming convention.

```
abc.xx.klm
abc.xx.xx.klm
abc.xx.xx.x.klm
```

I want to remove the part of the string before and including the first dot (`.`), and the part of the string after and including the last dot (`.`), and print as below:

```
xx
xx.xx
xx.xx.x
```

Is `split` the right function to use? If so, how?

Comment: Take a look at what `'abc.xx.xx.klm'.split('.')` gives you.  Then try taking the `[1:-1]` slice of that.

Answer (score 0):

The split / join technique is probably best but here's another option.

Just find the first and last '.' then slice on their positions.

```
file_names = ['abc.xx.klm', 'abc.xx.xx.klm', 'abc.xx.xx.x.klm']

for filename in file_names:
    s = filename.find('.')
    e = filename.rfind('.')
    print(filename[s+1:e])
```

**Output:**

```
xx
xx.xx
xx.xx.x
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
domain="abc.xx.klm"
newDomain=domain[:domain.rfind('.')]
newDomain=newDomain.split('.', 1)[-1]
print(newDomain)
```

Result

xx

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```py
file_names = ["abc.xx.klm", "abc.xx.xx.klm", "abc.xx.xx.x.klm"]

for file_name in file_names:
    # Split the filename using dot as delimiter
    parts = file_name.split('.')

    # Join the parts starting from the second part up to the second-to-last part
    new_name = '.'.join(parts[1:-1])
    
    print(new_name)
```

Output:

```
xx
xx.xx
xx.xx.x
```

Answer (score -1):

```
inputfile = ['abc.xx.klm','abc.xx.xx.klm','abc.xx.xx.x.klm']
out = ['.'.join(files.split(".")[1:-1]) for files in inputfile]
print(out)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
a=['abc.xx.klm', 'abc.xx.xx.klm', 'abc.xx.xx.x.klm']
for i in a:
    output=i.strip("abc.klm")
    print(output)
```